# GTK Maximum number of clients reached

Tags: arch-linux, chrome, cinnamon, gtk

I recently updated my arch linux running chromium and ever since the update I get the error

```
 Maximum number of clients reached Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
:0.0
```

when I try to run a program while chromium is running. If I start the application first and then chromium, everything is working fine.

I have chromium version 44.0.2403.157-1, kernel version 4.1.6-1, gtk 1.2.10-15 and cinnamon 2.6.13-3

Comment: Having the same issue on openbox. Have seen it happen with firefox and possibly steam.

Answer (score 2):

A [quick search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Maximum%20number%20of%20clients%20reached%20Gtk-WARNING%20**%3A%20cannot%20open%20display%3A) shows that there a lot of people with this error. Apparently, add-ons with poor code can cause a lot of trouble for the browser and Xorg. Here are a couple of solutions that I can think of right now.

- Start `Chromium` with the add-ons disabled and see if the issue is resolved.
- Uninstall `Chromium` and make sure to delete its data (cache, preferences, ...) wherever it's stored (most probably in the `/home` directory) and then reinstall it. Start it without any modifications and see if the problem persists.
- It also might be bug in `Chromium 44.0.2403.157-1`. Update `Chromium` to the [latest version](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/chromium/).
- Why are you using `GTK 1.2.10-15`? Why not use `GTK3+`? If you have no significant reason to use `GTK 1.2.10-15`, consider updating your `GTK`.

Comment: OP system is definitely not using `gtk1` when running `chromium` and installing `gtk3` (if not already installed) won't make any difference either. When installing `chromium`  (`gtk2` is one of the dependencies - you can see that if you follow the link in your post), the right `gtk` version is being pulled in automatically (the one that chromium was built against and uses at runtime).

Comment: @don_crissti Yeah, you're right. But still, using `GTK1` doesn't make sense. OP got the version right so I doubt that he made a mistake in his post.